# Kendall rank correlation coefficient's p-value

Tags: correlation, statistical-significance, p-value, kendall-tau

I'm trying to compute a p-value for a two tailed test following [Wikipedia formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall_rank_correlation_coefficient#Significance_tests) which indicates that:

> one computes Z, and finds the cumulative probability for a standard
> normal distribution at -|Z|. For a 2-tailed test, multiply that number
> by two to obtain the p-value

I'm using [this Rust's library](https://docs.rs/kendalls/0.1.5/kendalls/) which computes Tau value and then you can get the significance from this [source code](https://docs.rs/kendalls/0.1.5/src/kendalls/lib.rs.html#213-218).

The problem is that [this calculator](https://www.wessa.net/rwasp_kendall.wasp#output) (with default values) gives a *2-sided p-value = 0.0389842391014099*. Which is far from the p-value I'm getting. The steps I'm following are these:

1. Compute Tau
2. Compute the statistical significance: Z with `significance = kendall::significance(tau, x.len())`
3. Gets the CDF from Gaussian Distribution with sigma = 1 using [this GSL library's function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/randist.html#c.gsl_cdf_gaussian_P): `cdf = gaussian_P(-significance.abs(), 1.0)`
4. Multiply that value by 2

I'm getting a very different value: `0.011946505026920469`. I don't understand what I'm missing. Perhaps it's a misunderstanding of Gaussian distribution and it's sigma param. Any kind of help would be really appreciated

Comment: Seems to be a bug with the Rust's library: [issue](https://github.com/zolkko/kendalls/issues/2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was [a bug](https://github.com/zolkko/kendalls/issues/2) with the library. The described math was correct